# How to call the native browser from a j2me application

Tags: java, java-me

I want to go to a webpage, when I click a button inside my app. I am using J2ME.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
platformRequest("http://developers.sun.com/mobility");
```

[Platform requests](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/ttips/platformRequest/index.html)